# Is it possible to set the process group of a child process with PCNTL?

Tags: php, pcntl

The [man page for pcntl_waitpid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-waitpid.php) documents the following option:

> wait for any child process whose process group ID is equal to the absolute value of pid.

I'm interested by this feature (waiting for *some* child processes, but not all), but can't find any reference to *how to set the process group ID* of a child process.

Is this possible at all with [PCNTL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. PCNTL does not offer this function, but the [POSIX](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.posix.php) extension does offer [posix_setpgid()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-setpgid.php):

```
bool posix_setpgid ( int $pid , int $pgid )
```